# Decomposition of nxm matrix into 2 vectors under the influence of noise (estimation)

Tags: matrices, vectors, noise

I have given two matrices $A,N$ and two vectors $a,b$ with $A,N \in \mathbb{C}^{n \ast m}$ and $a, b \in \mathbb{C}^{n,m}$ where $A_{n,m} = a_n b_m + N_{n,m}$.

$N$ models white noise (gaussian distributed).

Given $A$ and $b_1 = 1$, how can I calculate the best estimation of $a$ and $b$?

(I already thought of LU decomposition and only use the first column of L and the first row of U as an initial estimation, but I doubt, that's the best possible estimation.)

[Edit 21.12.2015 21:49 UTC]

The best estimation of $a$ and $b$ is considered this one, having a minimal value of $Q := \sum_{j=1}^{m} {|| A_{j} - a b_j ||}^2$, where $|| \circ ||$ denotes the euclidian norm and $A_{j}$ is the $j$th column of $A$.

Comment: How are you measuring "best" estimate?

Comment: (Answered as an edit for the sake of readibility.)

Comment: That doesn't seem like what you actually want, given that $A_{i,j}$ is a scalar and you're using norm bars.

Comment: You're right, only one sum is needed. I will correct it.